# expect script regular expression not working

Tags: regular-expression, expect

In expect script I am trying to capture some text from output

Text in output is like `ivalue=16ef7baa-0de1-48bf-9e04-d486defbee1c,`

code:

```
expect -re {^(ivalue)\=(.*)(\,)$}
puts "expect_out (0, string)"
```

output :

```
[142C \r\u001b[7A\u001b[11C\u001b[?7h\u001b[0m\u001b[?12l\u001b[?25h" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "^(ivalue)\=(.*)(\,)$"? Gate "inum=*,"? gate=yes re=no
```

but unable to capture this value using regular expression

appreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

{...} is like shell single quotes. I think it makes your backslashes literal.